# Why doesn't js script work at django web-site?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm new in Django and JS. Trying to create HTML5 audioplayer with custom controls. When I start page nothing happens.

Tested this mp3 with default player and everything is ok. So I think static settings is correct.

#### Folder structure:

```
..stream (the app)
....static
......stream
........audio
..........test.mp3
........scripts
..........player.js
....templates
......index.html
```

This is my index.html. The base template is almost empty.

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static "stream/scripts/player.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <audio src="{% static "stream/audio/test.mp3" %}" type="audio/mpeg">
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my player.js

```
var aud = $('audio')[0];
aud.play();
```

I expect that when I open the page, the music would start playing.

Comment: Could you try with this player.js instead ? `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();`

Comment: Now if you load jQuery in base_generic.html, the problem is more to delay the execution of the function when the page is ready, otherwise the query by tag name won't find anything (another issue will be browsers options : many browsers block  automatic sounds)

Comment: @PRMoureu, unfortunately nothing. As I understand jQuery is a framefork. Can I write code with pure JS or I shoud use fameworks anyways?

Comment: If you check the source code generated, do you see the audio and JS script blocks ? or  any error  in the console ?

Comment: @PRMoureu, there aren't any troubles in console. This in a source <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        
    <h1>Stream</h1>

    
    <script src="/static/stream/scripts/player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <audio src="/static/stream/audio/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

    </body>
</html>

Comment: and what if you try `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();` directly in the browser console after the page is loaded ?

Comment: @PRMoureu, run this from python manage.py shell. Result: NameError: name 'document' is not defined

Comment: i mean the browser console sorry (right-click > inspect, or CTRL+MAJ+i)

Comment: @PRMoureu, eah, it works. Noticed this error before I typed this manually: player.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined at player.js:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the JS script execution.
At the time the browser executes

```
var aud = $('audio')[0];
aud.play();
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();
```

the audio block is not created yet, so the query cannot find anything and you get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

You can delay the execution with the following function :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var aud = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    aud.play();
}, false);
```

Comment: You're welcome, btw the $ expression `$('audio')[0];` refers to jQuery (in many cases). Be careful if you look at solutions involving it, you have to include jQuery sources or find the translation in pure javascript